# How to create 2 maps using Store Locator Plus plugin in wordpress

Tags: plugins, wordpress, maps

I am using **[Store Locator Plus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/store-locator-le/)** plugin for showing locations of stores, and plugin works fine. But now i need to create another map for distributor's location. So how can i use this plugin to create 2 maps at a time, something like i could divide the locations into 2 maps. Or can i use this plugin twice in an application, like renaming kind of things.

Please help.

Comment: You should try to create a separate page for distributor's locations and on that page place distributor's locations

Comment: there is no feature to select from locations and place them into different pages. It itself picks all the locations. there is only one shortcode for that, if i put that shortcode in different pages then it will show the same map.

Comment: In that case renaming not work. You should try to use two plugins of same type such as [Store Locator Plus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/store-locator-le/) and [WordPress Store Locator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/store-locator/), etc. These plugins are same in using. Having two different short codes, use 1st plugin short code at one place and 2nd plugin short code at other.

Comment: Yeah i tried that HiSBIT, but doing this shows all the locations on both pages. I need different locations on different page. That's my problem.

Comment: DO NOT mix Store Locator Plus and WordPress Store Locator.   They use similar data structure names and will fight with each other.   Store Locator Plus can do what you need if you have the right add-on pack.

Answer (score 1):

Store Locator Plus supports multiple maps which can filter locations by categories.  You can do this with the Tagalong add-on pack to add managed categories or Pro Pack add-on pack if you need simple free-form categories.

You then assign the category / tag "red" or "blue" to each location and use the shortcode filters:

[slplus only_with_tag="red"] on one page or [slplus only_with_tag="blue"] on the other.

Full documentation and examples are on the website at http://www.storelocatorplus.com/.   You should also post questions like this in the forum.   While I do use Stack Overflow regularly I answer support questions much more quickly at the support forum:

http://www.charlestonsw.com/forums/forum/support-2/